# How can i receive sms to my app when the app is closed or destroyed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms, android-service

I'm working on a SMS App which is almost done and works well, but it only receives the messages when the application is open or running on background, as soon as I close my app it stops receiving the messages.

**Manifest**

```
<receiver
        android:name=".SmsBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH">

        <intent-filter android:priority="999" >

            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />

        </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service android:name=".ServiceCommunicator"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE">

         <intent-filter>
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />
             <data android:scheme="sms" />
             <data android:scheme="smsto" />
             <data android:scheme="mms" />
             <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
         </intent-filter>
   </service>
```

**service.java**

```
public class ServiceCommunicator extends Service {

SmsBroadcastReceiver mSmsBroadcastReceiver;
IntentFilter mIntentFilter;


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mSmsBroadcastReceiver=new SmsBroadcastReceiver();
    mIntentFilter=new IntentFilter();

    mIntentFilter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");

    registerReceiver(mSmsBroadcastReceiver,mIntentFilter);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    unregisterReceiver(mSmsBroadcastReceiver);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

In the MainActivity.java i am starting the service by calling this:

```
StartService(new Intent(this,ServiceCommunicaor.class));
```

Comment: what device are you testing on?

Comment: If you copy/pasted this "StartService(new Intent(this,ServiceCommunicaor.class));"  you've got a spelling mistake in your class name.

Comment: testing with my mobile phone

Comment: no,there is no error , but i am not able to receive sms when the application is closed